# dotnetnuke form and list, delete/organise rows?

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I installed the form and list module and I configured it. I added some row but now I want to organise them or delete some rows, but I don't find any information about it...

So.. is it possible ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found how to delete a row, I had to select "HTML Buttons" for "Send Buttons". Now, when I edit a row, I have the choice between update, cancel and delete.

About the sorting problem, I don't think it's possible to organize the rows manually.